# Facet API block not displaying

Tags: search

To create a filter for my site I have installed following modules [Search api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api), [Search api db](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_db), [Facet api](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi)

I followed the steps mentioned in http://www.webwash.net/tutorials/intro-search-api-part-1-how-create-search-pages and http://www.webwash.net/tutorials/intro-search-api-part-2-faceted-search for creating facets.

I have created server and indexed my fields. Then I placed the Facet blocks in the particular region. But blocks are not displaying. Please  Let me know what mistake I have done. Thank You

Comment: Have you cleared cache? Have you correctly set up the block in terms of visibility etc?

Comment: Yes, I cleared all caches. I have set block to visible in all pages, but it is not displaying any wher @PotneySwitters

Comment: As far as I understand it shouldn't be visible at all pages but only at /search-page

Comment: I don't have search page how to display it in non search pages

Comment: On admin/structure/block find the block and edit where you want it to appear. The search page is not "yours". As far as I understand and according to the tutorials you posted it is coming along with them.

Comment: Already I tried it but not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30254/discussion-between-harsha-and-potney-switters).

Comment: Why are you using the database for search?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem. I desperately seeked a solution or even a little hint on the Internet but finally I figured it out.

My problem was about the database privileges of the default mysql user (the one with credentials in the settings.php). Facet api requires **Create Temporary Tables** privilege to run properly. And as you can tell, my db user was not granted that privilege. Running the following commands on mysql console solved the problem:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_db.* TO 'your_user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGS;
```

I hope this helps someone..